# webservice stopped working after moved from Windows Sever 2012R2 to 2019

Tags: wcf, iis-10

I have one old wcf developed with .Net Framework 4.0 and was hosted on Windows Sever 2012 R2.

It was working fine but after server upgrade to Windows Sever 2019, it is throwing following error:

> An error occurred while making the HTTP request to
> https://prod1-a1:8086/MainAuthService/Authentication.svc. This could be due to the fact that the
> server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the
> HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security
> binding between the client and the server.

IIS version is 10.

It is first time I am working with web service and I don't have clue. I don't have access to code but any help would be appreciable.

Comment: You are deploying a WCF app onto IIS but without proper configuration of the server certificate (as that message indicated), so you need to analyze the current status of Windows HTTP API mappings, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html and make adjustments. Talk to your domain/server administrators who should know more about the correct settings you should set.

Comment: The error likely is caused by the required TLS protocols not being  enabled.  To address this modify the registry entries to enable TLS1.1+ protocols. The Registry key can be found at `HKLM SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to resolve it by using full domain name with URL which has https.

```
https://prod1-a1:8086.pisc.com/MainAuthService/Authentication.svc.
```